# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.19.0 | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, openstack, nginx

I have a 502 Bad Gateway Error with `nginx`/1.19.0, when I press log in.
I saw other topics here but mine seems little different.
Because:

1. I don't have a `php` directory in `/etc`.
2. I don't have `nginx` directory in `/etc`.
3. I don't have a `uwsgi` service.

[image]

About my installation:

1. Clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
2. Did:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Ran:

   ```
   sudo snap install microstack --devmode --beta
   ```
4. Ran:

   ```
   sudo microstack init --auto --control
   ```

   [image: sudo microstack init --auto --control output]
5. Created password.
6. Browsed `https://192.168.0.1/` or `http:/`.

   Here I saw OpenStack login windows, entered login and password and got a 502 Bad Gateway error.

   [image: 502 Bad Gateway error]

What I do wrong?
How I can repair it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, in my case OpenStack chose the language "Ru" instead of "En" and for some reason this results in a 502 error for the Dashboard.

So I went to {hostip}/identity/, then went to the settings and changed the language to "En" (And set the correct time zone, but I don't think it's important).

After that, everything worked, if it helps you - let me know.

Thank you ;)

Comment: Wow, really! https://imgur.com/a/9HaLufT But in Webgui Is En ans in settings is Ru. Did u know, this WebGUI is work on Russian lang?

Comment: Also, have you been able to find out where this error came from? I put openstack with the help of microstack on 2 different VMs and 2 different servers and all the times I saw this error.

Comment: Я думаю проблема в том, что OpenStack по какой-то причине не работает с русской локалью, я поменял язык и дашборд заработал. Сейчас я столкнулся со второй проблемой, что не создаются ВМ. Теперь я намерен изменить лист репозиториев на оригинальный (Селектел проставляет свои зеркала), чтобы изменить язык при установке на "En", может это решит мою проблему.

Comment: I think the problem is that OpenStack for some reason does not work with the Russian locale, I changed the language and the dashboard worked. Now I am faced with the second problem that VMs are not created. Now I intend to change the list of repositories to the original one (Selectel puts its mirrors) in order to change the language when installed to "En", maybe this will solve my problem.